# Passing file type variable from one external javascript to another external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible? I saw a lot of questions about passing values from one external JS to another external JS, but i didn't (or maybe didn't notice) see anything about passing file from one external JS to another.

The thing is, i am building a web page consisting of 3 pages on it. First page is for uploading file using drag and drop, 2nd page is for formdata input and submitting formdata using AJAX, while 3rd page will show the responseText from AJAX. Each page has its own external script, because if i try to cram all the codes into 1 external javascript, it will show error *Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null* whenever i moved to 2nd or 3rd page, because the drag and drop box is located on the 1st page.

But i need to get the file dropped from external JS that handles the 1st page to the external JS that handles the 2nd page, because i need to append the file along with other data into the formdata, before submitting it with AJAX. So i want to know if there is anyway i can pass the file (along with the file info obtained with FileReader) from the external JS for 1st page to external JS for 2nd page? And if possible, any method that doesn't involve server side scripting (like PHP, JSP).

Comment: Don't use 3 different pages, just 3 different `<div>`s that you show/hide accordingly, this should fix your problem with having the code in one JS file.

Comment: But i think it should be ok to have 3 different pages too right? Just need to manage those 3 different JS used for each page, which is the problem that i currently facing now.

Comment: Merging everything to one page fixes your issues, why are you refusing to do so?

Comment: Because the team lead asked it to be separated. I already merged everything previously, and had all the codes in 1 sheet, but the team lead rejected it and wanted it to be separated.